# Default zoom for embedded PDF in Edge

Tags: html, pdf, embed, microsoft-edge

I want to zoom in an embedded PDF. The PDF is embedded this way:

```
<embed width="500" height="800" src="/path/to/file.pdf" type="application/pdf"></embed>
```

I would like the PDF to be zoomed (e.g. 120%) when initialized. I know this is possible if the Adobe plugin is used in Internet Explorer. But in Edge, the default Edge plugin is being used and I can't find any option to achieve this.

Has anyone an idea if and how it is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is not possible to zoom the embedded PDF for MS Edge (EDGE HTML) browser.

If you are available to use [MS Edge (Chromium)](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download) browser then you can zoom the PDF by adding the zoom argument to file name.

```
 <embed width="500" height="800" src="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf?#zoom=120" type="application/pdf"></embed>
```

Example:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
      </head>
      <body>
       <iframe width="500" height="800" src="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf?#zoom=120"></iframe>
       <object width="500" height="800" data="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf?#zoom=120" type="application/pdf"></object>
       <embed width="500" height="800" src="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf?#zoom=120" type="application/pdf"></embed>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Output in MS Edge (Chromium) browser:

[image]